# How do I get icons into the file menu with Griffon?

Tags: javafx, griffon

I am currently doing the Griffon tutorial MVC Groups (JavaFX). I dont get this running because I cant compile `griffon-app/i18n/messages.properties`. It says:
Caused by: griffon.core.editors.ValueConversionException: Can't convert `'org.kordamp.ikonli.javafx.FontIcon|fa-power-off' into javafx.scene.Node`

If I comment out this lines, it compiles and runs but of course it shows not icons. How do I get icons into the file menu with Griffon?

Comment: Please post the entire code block that is causing the error.

Comment: Full working code can be found at https://github.com/griffon/griffon/tree/master/samples/editor-javafx-java. Please check with any changes you've made on your own copy